# dir(sys) in python not giving the expected output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python program(test.py).I run this as

python3 test.py on Ubuntu 12.04 machine with python3 inst

```
import sys

dir(sys)


for i in sys.argv:
        print(i)


dir()
```

The output of the program is

```
test.py
```

which is the output of the for loop.I am referring to this online book
[Python Online Tutorial](http://swaroopch.com/notes/python_en-modules/)
 where I expect the output of dir(sys) to be

```
['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__name__', '__package__', '__s
tderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdout__', '_clear_type_cache', '_compact_freelists',
'_current_frames', '_getframe', 'api_version', 'argv', 'builtin_module_names', '
byteorder', 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 'displayhook', 'dllhandle'
, 'dont_write_bytecode', 'exc_info', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 'executable',
'exit', 'flags', 'float_info', 'getcheckinterval', 'getdefaultencoding', 'getfil
esystemencoding', 'getprofile', 'getrecursionlimit', 'getrefcount', 'getsizeof',
'gettrace', 'getwindowsversion', 'hexversion', 'intern', 'maxsize', 'maxunicode
', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path', 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platfor
m', 'prefix', 'ps1', 'ps2', 'setcheckinterval', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit
', 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'subversion', 'version', 'version_in
fo', 'warnoptions', 'winver']
```

Why don't I get that output?

Comment: When you're running a script, you only see output from `print` calls. `dir(sys)` shows output if you enter it in the Python console, but it needs `print` to show up while running the script.

Comment: In interactive mode, the interpreter executes `PRINT_EXPR` if the statement is an expression. That in turn calls `sys.displayhook`. If the value of the expression isn't `None`, `displayhook` writes the `repr` to `sys.stdout` and stores it to `builtins._`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir()` doesn't print anything, it just returns a value. You want `print(dir(sys))`.